# Passing value from controller to View in spring, angular js

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp

This is controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="doLogin")
    public ModelAndView doLogin(@ModelAttribute @Valid UserBean userBean,BindingResult result)
    {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("login");
        if(!result.hasFieldErrors())
        {

            if(!combatService.authenticateUser(userBean)) 
            {
                result.addError(new ObjectError("err", "Invalid Credentials"));

            } 
            else
                {
                 if(retrieveService.getdata(userBean) != null)
                 {
                     List<UserBean> username=retrieveService.getdata(userBean);
                     return new ModelAndView("welcomes", "usernames", username);    
                }   
                }
        }

        return view;
    }
```

This is angular js

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<div ng-init="usernames = ${usernames}">
<ul id="myUL">
 <li ng-repeat="x in usernames"><a href="#">{{x.username}}</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/maven_project/toLogin.obj"
            })

     .then(function (response) {$scope.usernames = response.data.usernames;
     alert('success');},
function (error) {
alert('failed');
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

This is error

```
    angular.js:14800 Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$parse/ueoe?p0=usernames%20%3D
 at q.consume (angular.js:15365)
    at q.primary (angular.js:15240)
    at q.unary (angular.js:15224)
 "<div class="md-form active-cyan active-cyan-2 mb-3" ng-init="usernames = ">"
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:14800
```

it passes the value from controller to view and it executes success but it didn't display any record. I try a lot and a lot. what is a problem anyone identifies the mistake

Comment: instead of returning ModelAndView from your rest controller return Response it will work

Comment: Its not working bro

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: error comes like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Comment: can you add the modified code for your rest Controller?

Comment: Bro, It's URL mapping problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove your `ng-init` directive, this is what gives the error, and I'm not sure what it's supposed to do.

It's sufficient to initialise `usernames` in the http response handler like you currently do.

hope this helps

Comment: Bro, I remove ng-init but also it's not working so it any version problem. I use this script tag <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: error comes like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"